# Unit Test android.provider

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

I'm trying to provide 100% test coverage and am stuck on certain Android methods, this is a good example:

```
public static boolean areMockLocationsEnabled(Context context) {
    return Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("1");
}
```

I can't mock Settings because it's using android.provider and not passed in. I've read about ProviderTestCase2 but I can't find many examples. Is there a way to mock or inject these android system settings?

Comment: This is my question, HOW do I unit test this method?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: There is no code, I don't know how to mock Settings as it is not passed in and is a a native Android provider. This is my question, how do I mock this?

Comment: You can mock it use a framework like `mockito` and run your other tests with `Robolectric`.

Comment: Jarred this is exactly what I said in my question, *how* do i mock a provider that isn't passed in?

Comment: I answered your previous question. What do you mean "not passed in?" Once again, you haven't posted any code that you have tried and where are you using 'provider' in your example. You do not really give anyone enough information.